# Why is the Debian package I've created for a single Python script empty?

Tags: debian, python, packaging

I have a quite simple Python project that might be very useful for some people. So I thought about packaging it. The project is called `maptool` and is a tool that allows people who have Panasonic cameras to add GPS information to it (see [repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/lumix_map_tool)).

I did the following steps according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ak-ZBYqQjg):

1. Created a folder `panasonic-maptool-1.0` with all the contents (`maptool.py`, a desktop launcher and an icon).
2. Created `.tar.gz` of this folder
3. Put the `.tar.gz` into the `panasonic-maptool-1.0` folder.
4. Run `dh_make -c mit -f panasonic-maptool-1.0.tar.gz` in that folder to create a "single binary package".
5. Inside of the `/debian` folder, I've adjusted `rules`, `control` and `copyright`.
6. Run `lumix_map_tool/panasonic-maptool-1.0$ fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage -F`

But when I look at the package that was created, it is empty. Can anybody please explain why?

All sources for the package creation are in the repository. One thing where I suppose I could have made an error is the rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

icon = $(CURDIR)/maptool-icon.png
script = $(CURDIR)/maptool.py
launcher = $(CURDIR)/maptool.desktop

DEST1 = $(CURDIR)/debian/maptool/usr/share/maptool
DEST2 = $(CURDIR)/debian/maptool/usr/share/applications

build: build-stamp

build-stamp:
    dh_testdir
    touch build-stamp

clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    rm -f build-stamp
    dh_clean

install: build clean $(icon) $(script) $(launcher)
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_clean -k
    dh_installdirs

    mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST1)
    mkdir -m 755 -p $(DEST2)

    install -m 666 $(icon) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(script) $(DEST1)
    install -m 777 $(launcher) $(DEST2)

# Build architecture-independent files here.
binary-indep: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
#   dh_installmenu
#   dh_installdebconf
#   dh_installlogrotate
#   dh_installemacsen
#   dh_installpam
#   dh_installmime
#   dh_installinit
#   dh_installcron
#   dh_installman
#   dh_installinfo
#   dh_undocumented
    dh_installman
    dh_link
    dh_compress
    dh_fixperms
    dh_installdeb
#   dh_perl
    dh_gencontrol
    dh_md5sums
    dh_builddeb

# Build architecture-dependent files here.
binary-arch: build install
# We have nothing to do by default.

binary: binary-indep binary-arch
.PHONY: build clean binary-indep binary-arch binary install
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `dh`. See `man dh`. What you are using there is old-style debhelper. `dh` is nicer and more compact. Just override the defaults as necessary. Looking at your rules file, I don't see any Python specific stuff. So it is probably not operating on the Python module. See also https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging. This contains worked examples, and also uses `dh`. You probably want Example 2. See the `override_dh_auto_install` stuff - that uses `dh`.

Comment: Ok, I see you have done all the installation stuff manually. You probably don't want to do that - it doesn't scale and it is error-prone. At a first glance it is not obvious why your package is empty. However, I suggest running debhelper in verbose mode. That will show you all the commands it is executing.

Comment: Actually, https://wiki.debian.org/Python/LibraryStyleGuide might be a better place to look. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1382569/350713

Comment: Incidentally, your chosen locations don't see standard. For example, why does your Python file go into `/usr/share/maptool`? This is not in any Python path I've ever heard of.